# XCode debug main app & today extension at same time

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I want to get `main app`, `today-extension` debug info at same time.

I run the scheme `main app` and got only `main app` debug info.
I try the attach by `Process Identifier(today-extension id)` but it's blank when I select `today-extension` process.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

> Basically select the Watch App as the scheme in xcode, hit build+run
>   which will build the iOS app and WatchKit app, install the WatchKit
>   app on to the Watch and attach the debugger to the WatchKit Extension.
>   Then in xcode select the iOS app in the scheme selector and select the
>   iPhone as the target device, launch the iOS app by tapping the app
>   icon on the phone and in xcode in the menu bar select "Debug > Attach
>   to Process" and select your app in the list. This should result in
>   having xcode attached to both processes at the same time. If you want
>   to debug something early in the iOS app's lifecycle you can select
>   "Debug > Attach to Process by PID or Name..." and type in the process
>   name of the iOS app prior to launching it manually. This way the
>   debugger will be attached right when the app launches.

From Apple Developer [site](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16003).

Note that they discuss WatchKit but it´s the same for Today Extension.

Comment: If launch app is not xcode, the xcode debug info will be blank

Comment: You need to attach your today extension project, Xcode > Debug > Attach to process and choose your extension.

Comment: yes i already do that,  but it still blank when i select extension process